# Linux: cat to named pipe in a python script

Tags: python, linux, pipe, subprocess, cat

I have a Java program that uses video from a framegrabber card. This program is launched through a python `launcher.py`.

The easiest way to read the video stream I found, is to make Java read on a named pipe, and this works perfectly. So my session is like:

```
$ mkfifo videopipe
$ cat /dev/video1>videopipe
```

and in a second terminal (since the `cat` command is blocking):

```
$ python launcher.py
```

I would like to automate this process. Unfortunately, the result is always the same: the Java application starts (confirmed through a print statement in the java program), but then the terminal stalls and nothing appears, exception or else.

Since this process works manually, I guess I am doing something wrong in the python program. To simplify things, I isolated the piping part:

```
from subprocess import call, Popen, PIPE, check_call

BASH_SWITCHTO_WINTV = ['v4l2-ctl', '-d /dev/video1', '-i 2', '--set-standard=4']
BASH_CREATE_FIFO_PIPE = ['mkfifo', 'videopipe']
BASH_PIPE_VIDEO = 'cat /dev/video1>videopipe'

def run():
    try:
        print('running bash commands...')
        call(BASH_SWITCHTO_WINTV)
        call(BASH_CREATE_FIFO_PIPE)
        Popen(['cat', '/dev/video1'], stdout=open('videopipe', 'w'))
    except:
        raise RuntimeError('An error occured while piping the video')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

which when run, outputs:

```
running bash commands...     
Failed to open  /dev/video1: No such file or directory
```

A little help would be very much appreciated :-)

Comment: `'-d /dev/video1'` is almost certainly a bug. `'-d', '/dev/video1'` should be two separate arguments. Same for `-i 2`. You may be able to use `'-d/dev/video1'` or `-i2` without the spaces, depending on the parser in use.

Comment: Which is to say: Your current error isn't coming from the `cat`, it's coming from `v4l2-ctl`.

Comment: ...because you're telling it to open a file named `<space>/dev/video1`, not `/dev/video1`.

Comment: That's also obvious in your error message, when fixed to show the formatting -- see how it has two spaces before the `/dev`, not one?

Comment: How much work does the actual Python script do? Seems like shell script would be simpler.

Comment: Actually, the script is also used as a launcher on windows, which is why it is in python

Comment: what happens if you give your java program `/dev/video1` instead of `videopipe`? I don't see what using the named pipe buys you in this case.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian yes indeed, it works without the need for a pipe. I realized that afterwards :-S However, I will have at least learned about named pipes :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `shell=True`, just pass a string:

```
BASH_PIPE_VIDEO = 'cat /dev/video1 > videopipe'
```

Currently, `cat` is passed to the shell as your script, and `/dev/video>videopipe` is passed to that shell as a literal argument -- not parsed as part of the script text at all, and having no effect since the script (just calling `cat`) doesn't look at its arguments.

---

Alternately, to avoid needless shell use (and thus shell-related bugs such as shellshock, and potential for injection attacks if you were accepting any argument from a non-hardcoded source):

```
Popen(['cat', '/dev/video1'], stdout=open('videopipe, 'w'))
```

---

On a note unrelated to your "cat to named pipe" question -- be sure you get your spaces correct.

```
BASH_SWITCHTO_WINTV = ['v4l2-ctl', '-d /dev/video1', ...]
```

...uses the name `<space>/dev/video1`, **with a leading space**, as the input device; it's the same as running `v4l2-ctl "-d /dev/video1"` in shell, which would cause the same problem.

Be sure that you split your arguments correctly:

```
BASH_SWITCHTO_WINTV = ['v4l2-ctl', '-d', '/dev/video1', ...]
```

Comment: I landed using `shell=True` after having tried a variety of other cleaner `subprocess` means. I'll correct that. I also isolated the problem a little more precisely (I think), as you'll see in the edit.

Comment: @Raoul, the new "isolated" problem is almost certainly unrelated to the `cat` process the question is asked about. See comments on the question itself.

Comment: fantastic, it works. The only thing left is that the `cat` command is still blocking, so I need to open the pipe with another program before it goes on to start my java program. Is there some way to make it nonblocking?

Comment: Yes, you can make it nonblocking, but I don't understand why you think you need to.

Comment: Your Java program reads from the pipe, right? That'll allow the `cat` to proceed.

Comment: Well, what you say absolutely makes sense, however, the shell waits for me to open the pipe (for example with vlc), and only then proceeds to the java startup command (also using `subprocess`). Which is to say the blocking part lies before java startup...

Comment: Ah ok, I just understood the problem. Many thanks to you!